# Backbone.js project configuration

Tags: git, backbone.js, github

Below was the instructions that I got at start of a course:

Setup
[clone the Backbone project](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone)
run bower install
[clone the backend server](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server/blob/master/README.md) 
launch the binary
point the --www flag to the root of the Backbone project
launch the project at http://localhost:8000

So I installed bower using `npm install -g bower` command 
then I used `git clone url` to clone the above listed github project and server. I am not sure what to do with launch the binary and --www flag to the root of backbone project. What does it mean and how to do..?
In case of binary I traversed to binary folder of server an ran a file

So how to do the next part --www flag to the root of backbone project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the instructions properly,

launch the binary
point the --www flag to the root of the Backbone project

is a single step. You need to launch the binary with a `--www` flag from terminal (Mac, Linux) or Command prompt in windows.

Let's say you cloned that [frontend](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone) project to `backbone-front` folder, and the backend project to a sibling folder named `backbone-back`

In windows you should be able to execute `./server_windows_amd64.exe --www ../../backbone-front` from the `backbone-back/binaries` folder via Command prompt.

Comment: so is there a an exe there so it gives me an error that it the file is not recoginized as internal or external command or batch file that error.this is what confusing me

Comment: @SachinDivakar you might be trying to execute it from the wrong directory. See http://superuser.com/questions/876933/running-exe-in-command-prompt. You need to provide your folder structures, a screenshot of error etc to give you additional info.

Comment: D:\Udacity\FrontEndFramework\FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server\binaries>server_windows_amd64.exe --www =D:\Udacity\FrontEndFramework\FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone

Comment: D:\Udacity\FrontEndFramework\FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server\binaries>
D:\Udacity\FrontEndFramework\FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server\binaries>server_darw
in_amd64.exe --www=D:\Udacity\FrontEndFramework\FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone
'server_darwin_amd64.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @SachinDivakar Weird. I'm on an ubuntu machine right now. Will test this with my laptop once I'm home.

Comment: okay thanks I am starting out to learn some framework and I kind of lost in configuration part installed the first mean application a simple helloworld test app and I wanted to know how to run it failed to get a answer here in SO .So decided to go harder way by learning it as course then its got stuck for the same reason configuring .And thanks bro taking the patience to help me out

Comment: @Please test it and tell me bro

Comment: @SachinDivakar You can just drag and drop the exe into command prompt and press enter, it'll execute it. This one seems to try to create some backing directory so you need to open command prompt as administrator. All that said, you don't really need a server and stuff to learn backbone. You can just use `.json` files as data source for a start. Try following https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/. If you need to serve your app from a static http server,  use abode brackets ide, it's free and it has a live preview option where you can serve `.html` file via node server

Comment: yes I did the problem is wth the equal bro it should not be there in windows just binary.exe --www  [space] pathtofrontend added that to your answer edited upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 1):

to any one starting out to code just now seeking help like me, in the binary files there are 3 files, each file is for a different oparting system (the .exe is for windows), if you cloned the project the windows version seems to be 0kb, you will need to go and re downaload it directly from the repository, then run the command with an .exe in the file name, good luck! ^^

server_windows_amd64.exe --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone 
using the cmd from the binary location
also make sure you not only installed bower on the computor but went into the backbone folder and excuted bower install to install the bower.json files

Answer (score 0):

I will take you through the entirety of installing the app on Windows. I just did it, and these instructions work. 
If you don't already have node or bower installed, Google "bower install on windows". The first page has the correct instructions. For clarification, the page's title is "How to install NodeJS, Bower, and Grunt..."

After that, you'll want to clone both the front end and the back end of the project. 
For the front end, follow these instructions here:
https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone
For the back end, follow these instructions:
https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server
@T J is correct. You'll want to be in ../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server/binaries when you run ./server_windows.amd64.exe

If you followed the above instructions correctly, then you should be able to launch the application at localhost:8000, which will give you a 404 page not found error. This is normal, because you haven't done anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct line to run from the binaries folder:

```
server_windows_amd64.exe --www ../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone
```

Then navigate to localhost:8000 and you will see the app.

Answer (score 0):

To `--www` flag to the root of your project you need to first determine what OS you are running on - you will need to determine which *binary file* to run from the [binary folder](https://github.com/udacity/FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server/tree/master/binaries). If you're on Mac OS maybe you would start your code with `server_darwin_amd64`. I am running on a Windows OS, so I would use `server_windows_amd64.exe`.

Next, *correctly* writing the whereabouts (directory) of your front-folder, where all the html, css and js are. i.e. `FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone`. I would imperatively use the equal sign here `=`. Here is where I would write: `--www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone` to open to the frontend folder.

In my bash terminal, when I `cd` into `FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone-Server/binaries`, I may run the program with the following code: `./server_windows_amd64.exe --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone`.

Lastly, you may find your site via http://localhost:8000

*NB: My frontend and backend folder are separated.*

Hopefully that helps, or gives you an idea on how to open up your program. :D